# module '__main__' has no attribute '__spec__' in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I run this code in Jupyter notebook but received the error module '**main**' has no attribute '**spec**' do you know what should I do? do you know what this error caused? because of PyTorch or related to Jupyter notebook?

```
def main():
    device = 'cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    train_dataset = VehicleDataset(mode='train')
    test_dataset = VehicleDataset(mode='test')
    train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=20, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
    test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=20, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
    # hyper-parameters
    num_epochs = 20
    lr = 0.0005
    model = VehicleLSTM(
        input_size=30, 
        hidden_size=256,
        output_size=2, 
        num_layers=1, 
        dropout=0.1, 
        device=device
    ).to(device)
    mse_loss = nn.MSELoss()
    l1_loss = nn.L1Loss()
    optim = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        for n_batch, (in_batch, label) in enumerate(train_loader):
            in_batch, label = in_batch.to(device), label.to(device)
            pred = model(in_batch)
            loss = mse_loss(pred, label)
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            optim.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optim.step()
        train_loss.append(epoch_loss)
        l1_err, l2_err = 0, 0
        lateral_loss, long_loss = 0, 0
        losses = []
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for n_batch, (in_batch, label) in enumerate(test_loader):
                if n_batch == 1:
                    in_batch, label = in_batch.to(device), label.to(device)
                    pred = model.test(in_batch)
                    if epoch == num_epochs - 1 and n_batch == 1:
                        print('pred: ', pred)
                        print('label: ', label)

                    l1_err += l1_loss(pred, label).item()
                    l2_err += mse_loss(pred, label).item()
                    lateral_loss += mse_loss(pred[:,:,0], label[:,:,0]).item()
                    long_loss += mse_loss(pred[:,:,1], label[:,:,1]).item()
        test_loss.append(l2_err)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

do you know what should I do? when I run those in the separate cell I receive this error :

```
TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\f\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\worker.py", line 185, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "C:\Users\f\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "C:\Users\f\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 86, in default_collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))

TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

is fine, all it does is running `main` function, when predefined `__name__` global variable is equal to `__main__` (which it is for jupyter notebook).

Look at last part of the error:

```
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>
```

`default_collate` is a `DataLoader` function (read more [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#working-with-collate-fn)) which is given multiple items from `dataset` (via `__getitem__` of `VehicleDataset` in your case) and constructs batch from it

For some reason, it returns `None`, while it should return one of `torch.Tensor`(probably), `np.array`, `dict` or other listed type, so:

- **Check what `VehicleDataset`'s `__getitem__` returns** (e.g. by `train_dataset[0]` and other value in the `range(0, len(train_dataset))`)
- Do the same for both `train_dataset` and `test_dataset`, understand when and why it returns `None`
- **Set `num_workers=0` when debugging, up the number if the whole pipeline works, it is easier that way.**